# Can the arguments BUFFER and DIRECT be used with expdp

Tags: oracle, buffer, datapump

I have a strange case where in what [this guy](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_expdp_tips.htm) says is not happening with me. I am not able to set the above two parameters neither through command line directly, nor using a par file.

expdp -help doesn't show any such arguments, so are there analogous arguments to BUFFER and DIRECT (from exp) in the data-pump version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, NO you can not and need not use these parameters
[Read this](http://oracledatapump.blogspot.com/2009/04/mapping-between-parameters-of-datapump.html)